# Is it possible to use pendrive as key for Linux system

Tags: linux, security, usb

I want to give high security for my linux box. 
So i planed to use my pen drive as key for my linux box.

How can i do it ?

Comment: What is your backup plan in case you loose your pen-drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additionally you can [authenticate by usb device](http://pamusb.org/) (including one time pads and any mix with other PAM modules of course). As tante said you can also store keys to harddrive on usb device.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to use a pendrive to decrypt and encrypt your harddrive, yes that is possible and actually not that complex. You can find full documentation at this Gentoo Wiki [article](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/SECURITY_System_Encryption_DM-Crypt_with_LUKS#Keyfiles_on_removable_media) (applies to other distributions as well)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, check out the Yubikey concept, from [Yubico](http://www.yubico.com/home/index/). Pretty nice.

I used to use pam_usb, like Maciej suggests, but the project's last release is three years old.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your whole Linux system on a 64G or 128G pendrive and boot from it. Your Linux box will be as secure as your pocket.

Comment: Do let me stress "secure as your pocket". Although not used for securing a whole box, I was using a thumb-drive on my (real) key chain as containing part of a key I needed to access a non-critical crypto (virtual) key-ring. I removed the thumb drive in order to take off a key, and *poof*, I need a new strategy (or at least redundancy).